# Searching an element's index in a numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, indexing, minimum

I have a "distances" numpy array. I want to find the index of an element. I used `numpy.where` condition but it is not returning the index. Instead, it is just returning the type of the element with an empty array, like so:

```
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

What should I do to get the index of the element? Please help. Thanks.

This is my code:

```
distances = distances_query_training(features_train, features_test[2])

print min(distances)

print type(distances)

pos = np.where(distances == 0.03471681)

print pos
```

And the following is the output:

```
0.0347168063061
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need all the close elements or just the best matching one?
I usually do something like this to get the closest index for a value

```
def nearest_arg(array, value):
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return idx
```

Comment: I needed the best matching one.
And your function works really well.
Thanks for the help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use equal to float values, use `isclose()`:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.rand(1000)

np.where(np.isclose(a, 0.3, atol=1e-4))
```